# How can i bind a network interface to an entire /48 subnet of IPv6 addresses without having to enumerate each and every individual address?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ipv6

#### Context

I need to know how to setup an entirely /48 IPv6 block in my server to perform **outgoing** requests with any of these IPv6 addresses without setting up each one individually.

My ISP provides this subnet via an **DHCP6** server connected directly to my machine on their data center.

The machine runs Ubuntu Server 20.04.

I've arleady tried this:

- `ip addr add 0000:000:00::/48 dev lo`, works really well with IPv4 adresses, i already get an /26 IPv4 block working this way for outgoing requests, but i can't with IPv6;
- `ip route add local 0000:000:00::/48 dev lo`, i can ping any IP locally using `ping6`, but i can't bind any TCP socket to the IP and perform outgoing requests, I receive `EADDRNOTAVAIL`;

### Question

Am I missing something?
How i can get this working?

### Resourses

#### Netplan config

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp132s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

#### Other Serverfault questions

- [How to bind a range of ips to ubuntu interfaces](https://serverfault.com/a/934511);
- [Adding a whole IPv6 /64 block to an network interface on debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/590038/adding-a-whole-ipv6-64-block-to-an-network-interface-on-debian);
- [Assign Entire IPV6 /64 Subnet to Network Interface [duplicate]](https://serverfault.com/questions/797527/assign-entire-ipv6-64-subnet-to-network-interface);
- [Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3):

Your second Server Fault link [outlines what is required](https://serverfault.com/a/591435/241174). Routed prefix to you, local route on that host, and allow non local IP in socket also known as IP_FREEBIND. EADDRNOTAVAIL implies step three is incomplete.

Confirm your routed prefix and local route works by pinging an IP in it from a different IPv6 network.

On Linux, allow bind to other IPs by creating `/etc/sysctl.d/freebind.conf` containing

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

Applications should bind to a desired IP address. Otherwise if not provided, the usual source address selection would pick some local IP assigned to an interface. Also possible to set IP_FREEBIND option on a per socket level.

Note that even without this routed prefix trick, a large number of IP addresses can be assigned to a host. Possibly several thousand before neighbor discovery becomes a problem.

---

IPv6 subnets should be /64 in size. Standardizing on lower half interface ID, upper half aggregation for routing. As router, this host might still be routed a /48, but only needs a /64 on the loopback route to itself.

Number of IP addresses is not important, as 2^64 is already effectively unlimited in size. Perfectly fine to only use one or two /64s out of a /48, leave room in the address plan for other things.

Comment: I can successfully ping only the DHCP assigned IPV6.

Comment: Do you mean an echo reply from the one IA_NA IP address, or something in a IA_PD delegated prefix?  Try getting a single IP address from your prefix working first, assigned to an interface and routed.